# How to change RVM gemset using bash script?

Tags: rvm, cron

I need to set up a cronjob that would run some ruby script on particular gemset, I have tried to write a shell script where I change RVM gemset using `/home/user/.rvm/bin/rvm use @spider`, but it gives me the following error: `RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you should load RVM as a function using something like this:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" && rvm use @spider
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a .rvmrc file to select a gemset (just cd to the specific directory) ?